# How to remove the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is the code to convert html to image using canvas..
I have one question like, when i clicks on the preview button the image is getting populated but if again try to click on the preview  button , the two preview image is appearing.

How can I remove the first preview?

```
   <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>Codepedia.info</b> is a programming blog. Tutorials focused on Programming ASP.Net,
            C#, jQuery, AngularJs, Gridview, MVC, Ajax, Javascript, XML, MS SQL-Server, NodeJs,
            Web Design, Software</p>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>html2canvas</b> script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts
            of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as
            such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation.
        </p>
    </div>
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to remove any existing child divs from the `#previewImage` div before creating a new preview, so just use `$("#previewImage").empty();` before invoking `html2canvas`, or right after saving the image to disk.

For example:

```
$("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
     $("#previewImage").empty(); // <-- this
     html2canvas(element, {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
            getCanvas = canvas;
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks u so much ...it helped..:)

Comment: One doubt,i added some buttons inside that div,after settings  that div as empty , then buttons are not displaying

Comment: @Questions: if you only want to remove the `canvas` element, you can use `$("#previewImage canvas").remove()` instead.

Comment: Thank u so muchh..:)